# Pandoc has stack size error?

Tags: linux, html, mediawiki, pandoc, stack

I am attempting to use pandoc to convert an HTML file to a MediaWiki format. I'm getting the following error. (It is a large file, so it wouldn't surprise me if this is the issue.)

I have googled the error message, but no results I could find seemed sensible/understandable.

```
pandoc run_faster.html -f html -t mediawiki -s -o run_faster.txt
Stack space overflow: current size 16777216 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

What exactly is causing the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What happened when you followed the suggestion on the third line and what size (in bytes) did you try? `pandoc +RTS -K100000000 -RTS run_faster.html -f html -t mediawiki -s -o run_faster.txt` A bit of Googling suggests that pandoc needs to compiled with RTS options enabled for this solution to work: `cabal install --ghc-options=-rtsopts=all`

Comment: I haven't tried the suggestion on the third line because I was unsure of where to put it in the command and what exactly it might do. I'm afraid you'll need to be more specific with your instructions, because I am on a relatively beginner level with Linux. I'm unfamiliar with `+RTS -Ksize -RTS` and `cabal install --gch-options=-rtsopts=all`. I don't understand what either is doing. Note that I use Ubuntu 14.04. @MikeFitzpatrick

Comment: You should insert `+RTS -K100000000 -RTS` into your command at the position I've suggested in my first comment. This will increase pandoc's stack size from 16777216 bytes to 100000000 bytes _iff_ your copy of pandoc supports `rstopts` and this will hopefully sidestep your stack size issue. If you get the same error try increasing the stack size further. If you get a different error then your copy of pandoc might not have been compiled with `--ghc-options=-rtsopts=all`

Comment: Worked like a charm. I figured it was basically like this, but I wasn't familiar with the command, so it was helpful to have some guidance. If you post this as the answer, @MikeFitzpatrick, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the pandoc's default stack size using `+RTS -Ksize -RTS` in your command as follows:

```
pandoc +RTS -K100000000 -RTS run_faster.html -f html -t mediawiki -s -o
```

This will increase pandoc's stack size from 16,777,216 bytes to 100,000,000 bytes.

If you get the same error try again with a larger stack size.

If you get a different error then your copy of pandoc might not have been compiled with `--ghc-options=-rtsopts=all`